# Can we sample texture attached to inactive FBO slot?

Tags: opengl

Can I attach two textures to one FBO, and switch between them using `glDrawBuffers`, binding the inactive one as shader input? This seems much more efficient than switching FBOs for multipass effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're assuming you don't have access to [OpenGL 4.5/ARB/NV_texture_barrier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Barrier), no [you cannot](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model#Framebuffer_objects). The part of the OpenGL specification that forbids feedback loops on framebuffer attached images *does not care* whether the image can be written to or not. This is also true for array layers or mipmap levels; reading from one layer while writing to another layer will not save you.

All that matters is *attachment*. You must either bind a new FBO that doesn't have the texture attached, or remove the attachment from the current FBO.

Though again, texture barrier functionality makes everything I said irrelevant. And [considering how widespread it is](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?extension=GL_NV_texture_barrier), it's really not something you should be concerned about.

Comment: Thanks, that's a bummer since the extension isn't available in ES3.0/web.